# A question of "not this one"

Tags: grammar

It's hard to explain my question.

I saw(or heard) "not this one." at some place, but "not" is an adverb, and "this one" is a noun.

Is this sentence "not this one." grammatically correct? Because as I learned before, adverbs can't modify nouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands "Not this one" is not a sentence because it has neither a subject nor a verb. If someone says "Not this one" they are usually using a shortened form of a full sentence where 'not' modifies a verb and 'this one' is the object of the verb.

An example of such a sentence would be:

> The one you need is **not this one**

You might hear this in a warehouse where orders are being picked and the speaker is telling the picker not to take the item the speaker is pointing to.

You might also hear someone say 'not this one' when they are directing the driver of a vehicle. In this case the full sentence might be:

> The turning you need **is not this one**

We shorten sentences in this way all the time, in most cases we would never use the full sentence because it's too clumsy and the meaning is clear from the context.

Other examples of shortened sentences are "Look out!" Which is a warning and a shortened form of "You **look out!**" and "take the next right" which is an instruction to a driver and is a shortened form of "You must **take the next right** turning".

Answer (score 0):

I think with this usage the verb is implicit in the context.

E.g.

> Who did it?
>
> Not him

Implied:

> Who did it?
>
> He did not do it

The **not** modifies the verb **do**